# Find the index of the List items - WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have listbox which contains buttons listed vertically with related datas as given below;

```
<ListBox Name="CTransactionList" Margin="0,0,0,0"   >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="400" Height="200" Background="#6A040B2E" Click="completetransact">
                                <Button.Content >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200" Width="400">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Type1}" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                                                <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="22" Text="Name:" Height="30"/>
                                                <TextBlock Width="200" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Date1}" Height="30"/>

                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                                                <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="22" Text="Difficulty:" Height="30"/>
                                                <TextBlock Width="200" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Amount1}" Height="30"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                                                <TextBlock Width="110" FontSize="22" Text="TotalTime:" Height="30"/>
                                                <TextBlock Width="200" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Time1}" Height="30"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                                                <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="22" Text="Distance:" Height="30"/>
                                                <TextBlock Width="200" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Dis1}" Height="30"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="65">

                                                <TextBlock Width="290" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Def1}" Height="65" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

And I'm binding the data with such classes;

```
[DataContract]
    public class CTransaction
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String Date1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Amount1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Type1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Time1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Dis1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Def1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Cdate1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Strpt1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Endpt1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Index1 { get; set; }

        public CTransaction(String date1, String amount1, String type1, String time1, String dis1, String def1, String cdate1, String strpt1, String endpt1,int index1)
        {
            this.Date1 = date1;
            this.Amount1 = amount1;
            this.Time1 = time1;
            this.Dis1 = dis1;
            this.Def1 = def1;
            this.Cdate1 = cdate1;
            this.Strpt1 = strpt1;
            this.Endpt1 = endpt1;
            this.Index1 = index1;
            switch (type1)
            {
                case "FR":
                    this.Type1 = "Images/a.png";
                    break;

                case "TA":
                    this.Type1 = "Images/b.png";
                    break;

                case "DA":
                    this.Type1 = "Images/c.png";
                    break;

                case "CC":
                    this.Type1 = "Images/mount.png";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As shown above, I have a data binding named Index1 which indexes the button with an arbitrary integer. I want to remove a specified indexed button by user with this code;

```
ctransactionList.RemoveAt("index comes here");
```

My exact desire is to remove the clicked button,(i.e. if the second button clicked, then remove the second one). And I tried to embed some indexes(i.e. Index1) in it to remove it, I couldn't find any possible way; I also failed again.

This is the way I tried;

The removal code given above only removes the indexed item based on the whole list item count. I mean, for example, the first element always has the '0' index. It does not care my Index1 data.(I can retrieve the Index1 data with selectedButton as sender method) I wish I could have removed the button which includes the user-specified Index1 data.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.
(Windows Phone 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding click event handler for button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var item = button.DataContext as CTransaction;
    if (item != null)
    {
      ctransactionList.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

ctransactionList should be an ObservableCollection.